# How to limit range in time picker in Ionic?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a form in my mobile app where the user has to submit the start and end time for their reservation. I want to restrict the time range that the user can select, assuming that a certain establishment can only allow reservations within their open hours (ex: 10:00am-9:00pm).

Unfortunately, this cannot be achieved using the ion-datetime. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Do you need only select to time or both date and time ?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using `ion-datetime` if you split the date and times selection into seperate fields, one for date and one for start and end time, as follows, note the use of the `min` and `max` attributes for the limits:

```
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="date" display-format="YYYY-MM-DD">
        </ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Start Time</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="startTime" display-format="HH:mm" min="10:00" max="21:00">
        </ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>End Time</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="endTime" display-format="HH:mm" min="10:00" max="21:00">
        </ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>
```

You can then join them in the component before form submission if you want to store them as one value, this could be done with simple string concatenation - `reservation = ${this.date} ${this.startTime}-${this.endTime} // YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm-HH:mm` as the return value is a string. Or use [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) to do something more involved.

Comment: This should have been accepted answer.
min="10:00" max="21:00"